# Someone who lacks literacy is illiterate or barely literate; is there a similar noun or phrase to describe someone who can barely type?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request, nouns

Someone who lacks literacy is illiterate or barely literate; is there a similar noun or phrase to describe someone who can barely type?

"Barely able to type" doesn't roll off the tongue very well.

Comment: How much does it matter that a phrase or expression "rolls off the tongue"?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey When you attempt to combine it with "illiterate" in the same sentence, "barely able to type" doesn't work too well.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey ideally, everything you say should sound nice, or at least not ill-fitting. This is most true of public speakers, but it can be true of other native speakers, and I would argue that it’s most important to non-native speakers, who want to find expressions for things to demonstrate their knowledge of English, for any number of reasons (a job or job interview, impress people they know, etc., etc.).

Comment: @MichaelHarvey we have `word-request` and `phrase-request` for this reason; that you can find succinct expressions so that you don’t have to spell things out at great length.

Comment: I would merely say that someone is, or is not, a a skilled typist. The art of typing has not been in existence long enough to have acquired a compact expression for ability or the lack of it, unlike writing.

Comment: The closest word would be *Semi-literate:* (b) able to read but unable to write. [M-W]. OR *agraphic* or *dysgraphic*. (But these are for a person who can't write.)

Comment: Poor at typing, poor typist ?

Comment: Has mild keyboard dyspraxia might fit the bill.

Answer (score 1):

The term that might be the most relevant is *[computer illiterate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_literacy)*, as those who can’t type well usually don’t know their way around a computer at all. But there are some other terms that you could use with slightly different meanings.

*Typing illiterate*. While this isn’t a term I’ve heard used before, you can find plenty of [examples](https://www.scubaboard.com/community/threads/questions-on-becoming-a-rescue-diver.321686/) of it online.

*Typing impaired*. Again, there are [examples](https://www.abuzztech.com/google-docs-now-has-voice-dictation/) of it online.

*Hunt and peck*. This is a specific poor typing style where a person uses two fingers to type and has to stare intently at the keyboard to hit the right keys. There is a [noun version](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hunt-and-pecker).

*Fat finger*. It means being [clumsy at typing](https://funkyenglish.com/slang-fat-fingers/), usually by accidentally typing multiple keys at once.